# My css files takes too much time too load slowing my web app

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, requirejs, less

My CSS files take too much time to load thus js files loads after 10 to 15 seconds and the view appears after 20 seconds.

```
    <script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.min.js"> </script>
    <link href="lib/css/bootstrap_v2.0.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/final_lib.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style_v2.0.49.css">
```

above is the structure of the index.html

I am stuck in loading CSS and js, and if I load CSS asynchronously than the page look is very poor and looks like scattered from all where.

Comment: try to put `<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.min.js"></script>` before `</body>` and then check again.

Comment: i was doing the same priviously but still n effect, the css blocks the js to load.

Comment: Did you try minifying the css files? Got Gzip enabled on the server? Might want to check out this: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: ya i have.. no solution

Comment: Got a url so we could check some things out?